# How Decode Password

Tags: mysql, encryption, passwords, decode

I have an old database and when I join the table of user I see

```
"username"=>"Mark"
"password"=>"db55668c3b3ea5877670599dce51abda"
"encrypted_password"=>"1fd0eb3ad6e4d1229012bc5ab872b841b25b7930557e49ed3ec7f573b28157b8aed2bdd1e5d0c368752ed6034653bf47fc11cb6e5a83d599c8a9455666827e64"
"password_salt"=>"gLwk7qWpxomnujSQyrKP"
```

and other table

```
nickAdmin : admin
passAdmin : UG0EMA0iBzJaaQJjVHcFdVJrWSNRIQ==
```

my question is What the type of each encryption and how I can Decode?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Marks's `password` looks like a hex encoded hash. Dehexing it gets 128 bit so maybe a md5 hash, but it could any 128 bit hash, or 128 bit encryption with the key stored elsewhere.

encrypted_password with salt probably indicates a salted hashed password. Don't bother attacking this.

passAdmin - looks base64 encoded but not to a plain text password.

Best bet is to find the code associated with each of these passwords and follow the same algorithm to generate a new password.